# Javascript and HTML Problems

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

having trouble getting this to run with node

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use(express.static('public')) //adds content of public folder

app.get('/', function (req, res){
       res.sendFile('/views/index.html', {root: __dirname})
})

app.listen(1337, function (){
    console.log('lab5-server.js listening on 1337')
})
```

it was running perfect yesterday and now it's not.  There's also an issue with the .html portion, it wont display the image I have assigned.  Quick note it that I left out most of whats written below the source code for the image, it's not necessary for this question.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1> <center> Welcome to Matt's Page </center></h1>

<center> <img src = "images/AlgorithmofSuccess.jpg"/> </center>
```

Does anyone see where I went wrong and why the terminal is returning "unexpected token" on the javascript portion?

Comment: if that is all, `__dirname` is not defined

Comment: "why the terminal is returning "unexpected token" on the javascript portion" — It isn't

Comment: @johnSmith — https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_dirname

Comment: Can we improve the title of this one?

Comment: sure how would you like me to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this, just had to change the folder of the lab5-server.js file i was using, thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use the `path` module to help point to your public path. I can give you an example:

```
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
const publicPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "./public");

// We point to our static assets
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "./public")));

app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("index.html", { root: path.join(__dirname, "./public") });
});

// And run the server
app.listen(1337, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Make sure that `./public` or `./dist` path contains your index.html